# Reusing content of an external webpage in DITA-OT

Tags: dita

I tried different method to include the content of an external webpage by url in dita files without success. Is it possible to do it? I can add references to my dita files:

```
<related-links>
<link href="http://example.com" format="html" scope="external"/>
</related-links>
```

however I am not able to ddisplay the content of the page in oXygen.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: It depends on the external sources and on your publication targets. If you want to publish to *PDF*, your content needs to be available offline.

What do you exactly mean with *content*? You can use external sources, e.g. images, if you just publish to *html5*. Just use the image URL in the *href*. If you publish to *pdf*, it would not work. The DITA-OT does not download things for you. Most websites are dynamic, so content is not very static so it may not work as you might expect. Maybe the external website has an API to gather the data you need. Or maybe it would be safer to use the [depend.preprocess.pre](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.4/extension-points/plugin-extension-points-pre-processing.html) extension point to hook in an Ant Target to download the external sources via <[get](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)> or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/). Another approach would be [dita-glass](https://github.com/oxygenxml/dita-glass) for on-the-fly conversion. But, it depends...

Comment: We have static links to JIRA issues. I need several data in our PDFs from the issue pages. It would be easier to pull the data during the transformation from the webpages than copy the relevant information one by one.